# ORACLE trigger compilation

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I have a problem with trigger transformation.
I have 2 tables: Filmy(od_film, rok_vyd-integer)and Komentare(id_film, dat_kom:date)
And i need to ensure that you can ony commnet the film after it was recored and publicised. But my trigger cannot by compiled. Thanks for hepl, I am just starting with sql...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "XVIKD00"."DATUM_KOMENTAR" 
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON KOMENTARE
    FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
    DATUM_KOMENTAR EXCEPTION;
    ROK  date;
BEGIN 
    SELECT KOMENTARE.DAT_KOM into ROK
    FROM FILMY JOIN KOMENTARE ON KOMENTARE.ID_FILM=FILMY.ID_FILM;
    IF(:NEW.(YEAR(rok)) < FILMY.ROK_VYDANIA) THEN
        RAISE DATUM_KOMENTAR; 
    END IF; 
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN DATUM_KOMENTAR THEN 
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2009,'Dátumy nie su v správnom časovom slede'); 
END;
```

Comment: If code "cannot be compiled", that implies that there is an error.  Post the error, don't make us guess.

Comment: This is wrong: `:NEW.(YEAR(rok)`. There must be a column name after `:NEW.`, expression like year(something) is not allowed.

Comment: @kordirko. Probably YEAR(:New.rok)

Comment: I wonder. Is it possible in your application to post comments for some movies if ones are not exists in database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess at the compilation errors, I would guess that

- You are calling a function `year` which does not exist.  `year` is not a function that exists in Oracle (unless, of course, you've created it).  You would either need to define your own `year` function or do something like `extract(year from rok)`.
- `:new` is a pseudo-record so you can only reference columns from it (i.e. `:new.<<column_name>>`.  `:new.(year(rok))` does not make sense.  You might mean `year(:new.rok)` but `rok` is a local variable so it wouldn't be part of the `:new` pseudo-record.  You might mean `year(:new.dat_kom)`.  You'd still need to resolve the issue that the `year` function doesn't exist.
- `FILMY.ROK_VYDANIA` in your `IF` statement isn't valid.  At that point, there is no `FILMY` to use to provide scope for the variable.  Perhaps you want to look up the `rok_vydania` from `filmy` using the `:new.id_film` and store that in a local variable to compare against `:new.dat_kom`?

Assuming that you fix those, you'll get one of two runtime errors.  A `SELECT INTO` statement throws an error if it returns anything other than 1 row and yours will undoubtedly return multiple rows unless you have only a single film in the database.  A row-level trigger also cannot query the table on which it is defined without causing a mutating table exception.  My guess is that you want

```
SELECT KOMENTARE.DAT_KOM 
  into ROK
  FROM FILMY 
       JOIN KOMENTARE ON KOMENTARE.ID_FILM=FILMY.ID_FILM;
```

to be

```
SELECT FILMY.ROK_VYDANIA
  INTO <<new local variable>
  FROM FILMY
 WHERE FILMY.ID_FILM = :new.id_film;
```

And, finally, from a style standpoint, it doesn't make sense to `RAISE` an exception in an `IF` statement only to catch that exception and call `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR`.  Just call `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` at the outset.

My guess, therefore, is that you want something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "XVIKD00"."DATUM_KOMENTAR" 
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
  ON KOMENTARE
  FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
  l_ROK_VYDANIA filmy.ROK_VYDANIA%TYPE;
BEGIN 
  SELECT FILMY.ROK_VYDANIA
    INTO l_ROK_VYDANIA 
    FROM FILMY
   WHERE FILMY.ID_FILM = :new.id_film;

  IF( extract( year from :new.dat_kom ) < l_ROK_VYDANIA )
  THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-2009,'Dátumy nie su v správnom časovom slede'); 
  END IF;
END;
```

Of course, this is just a guess since you haven't provided a reproducible test case that we can use to validate against.